# Attribute based validation of number of items in an IEnumerable parameter URL

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I am looking for something similar to [RangeAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.rangeattribute?view=netcore-3.1), which specifies the numeric range constraints for the value of a data field.

I want the validate based on the number of items in an IEnumerable parameter URL.

For example

```
[Route("foo")]
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult<SomeResponse>GetFoos([FromQuery] idList idList)
{
   // Validate model and get stuff
}

public class IdList
{
    // Obviously, the Range attribute is wrong here
    [BindRequired, Range(1, 10, ErrorMessage = "Expected 1 to 10 ids.")]
    public List<string> Id { get; set; }
}
```

Using .NET Core 3.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

`[Required, MinLength(2, ErrorMessage = "Pick at least 2 items."), MaxLength(4, ErrorMessage = "Pick at most 4 items.")]`.

Or you can create your own [custom model validation attribute, and custom client-side validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-3.1#custom-attributes).

Comment: Works perfectly to trigger the upper limit. Note that with a lower limit of 1, the lower error message is not triggered since the Required already checks for that.

Comment: On a side note, any idea how to required only non-empty strings in the List<string>?

Comment: Nothing on my mind currently except either create your own attribute, or you can have another property to check against that constraint like this: `[Range(minimum: 2, maximum: 4, ErrorMessage = "Expected 2 to 4 non-empty ids.")]
        public int NonEmptyIds
        {
            get
            {
                return Ids != null ? Ids.Where(a => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(a)).Count() : 0;
            }
        }`